# Gradle: exclude dependencies provided from compileOnly from fat jar

Tags: java, gradle, deployment, fatjar

I have a huge dependency (Spark) that I use in `compileOnly` configuration, and several other libraries. I am trying to build a fat jar, of course, without `compileOnly` dependencies. Gradle does this fine, however, several libraries declare `compile`/`runtimeOnly` dependencies that are also dependencies of `compileOnly` huge dependency, like:

```
my-module
|-> compileOnly: spark
|   ...
|   \-> compile: scala-reflect
|   ...
\-> implementation: library
    ...
    \-> runtimeOnly: scala-reflect
```

That causes `scala-reflect` to be included into jar as runtime dependency, that I am trying to avoid. Scala is taken here only as example, there are actually more like that (Jackson, parts of Apache Commons, …).

*Is there way to enforce `compileOnly` trainsitional dependencies?*

As I can see, I can manually `exclude` those transitive dependencies and redeclare them as `compileOnly`, but that would be a little mess (did I miss any? did I excluded something that is not actually provided?).

Comment: How do you build the fatjar?

Comment: I am using [`shadow` plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow) that takes outputs of compilation and, by default, adds everything from `runtimeClasspath` configuration. I am trying not to add something to `runtimeClasspath`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enforce the shadow plugin to remove those unneeded dependencies via the `dependencies` directive.

for example:

```
shadowJar {
  dependencies {
    exclude(dependency('org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:.*'))
  }
}
```

More info here
https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/#filtering-dependencies